# Callback in datatable

Tags: shiny, dt

In general I want to apply style **(border-top and fontWeight)**  in the last row of table. But there are a few tables in my app which I dont want to apply this style in the last row. I am using **callback( )** in DT to solve this but it does not work with **server = TRUE** option. The problem I have with **server = FALSE** is that it returns some weird formatting and loads slower. Any alternative solution to work with server = TRUE?

```
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(
        HTML("
    table.dataTable tr:last-child td {
      border-top: 1px solid #111 !important;
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight:600;
      color: #1c273c;
        letter-spacing: .5px;
    }"))),
    
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             dataTableOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    test.table <- data.frame(lapply(1:8, function(x) {1:1000}))
    test.table[c(2,3,7), c(2,7,6)] <- NA
    id <- which(is.na(test.table))
    
    output$table <- renderDataTable({
      
      DT_ignorelast <- function() DT::JS("$('table.dataTable tr:last-child td').attr('style', 'border-top : none !important; font-weight', '400');")
      
      datatable(
      test.table,
      callback = DT_ignorelast())
      
    },
    
      server = TRUE)
    
  }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you want?

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

css <- "
.lastRow {
  border-top: 1px solid #111 !important;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #1c273c;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
}
"
drawCallback <- JS(
  "function(settings){",
  "  var table = this.api();",
  "  var nrows = table.rows().count();",
  "  $(table.row(nrows-1).node()).find('td').addClass('lastRow');",
  "}"
)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(css))
    ),
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             DTOutput('table')
      )
    )
  ),
  
  server = function(input, output) {
    
    test.table <- data.frame(lapply(1:8, function(x) {1:1000}))
    test.table[c(2,3,7), c(2,7,6)] <- NA
    id <- which(is.na(test.table))
    
    output$table <- renderDT({
      datatable(
        test.table,
        options = list(
          drawCallback = drawCallback
        )
      )
    },
    server = TRUE)
    
  }
)
```